# jsonobject = new JSONObject(jsonArray.getString(index) vs jsonArray.getJSONObject(index)

Tags: java, json

I have created a JSONArray of Category object which include Item object List(JSONArray) in google appengine, thus, using `com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONObject` I validate the resulting String here http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and it fails.

However, at that site, if I just validate JSONObject of Category with Item List (JSONArray), the string is validated as Valid.

If I try JSONArray of Category without Item List, the string is also Valid.

Anyway, I tried to parse a JSONArray of Category which include Item List(JSONArray) with `org.json.JSONObject @version 2012-05-29` on my own:

if I parse for Category like `JSONObject jsonObj =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);` I get `org.json.JSONException: Value ...`

However I can parse for Category `JSONObject jsonObj =new JSONObject(jsonArray.getString(i));`

Once, I get the Category JSONObject, I can parse for Item like this `JSONObject jsonItem = jsonItemArray.getJSONObject(j);` fine.

I am confused with the discrepancy between `jsonobject = new JSONObject(jsonArray.getString(index)[SUCCESS] vs jsonArray.getJSONObject(index)[FAILED]` for my JSONArray of JSONObject with JSONArray.